# Fetched data from private CloudKit database not returning from function

Tags: swift, database, fetch, cloudkit

I'm trying to fetch some data from a private ClouKit database. The query and predicate is working fine because I can see at `print(data) // 1` that the array is filled with all the data. But as soon as it leaves `perform(){}` the array is resetted to it's at the top defined values and it just returns them.

```
func fetchUserRecord() -> [Double] {
    var data: [Double] = [0, 1, 2]                              //demo data
    let aWeekAgo = Date().addingTimeInterval(-604800)
    
    let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Date > %@", aWeekAgo as NSDate)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ProgressionValue", predicate: predicate)

    privateDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
        guard let records = records else { return }
        for record in records {
            data.append(record["Value"] as! Double)
        }
        data.append(0.0)
        print(data)         // 1
    }
    print(data)             // 2
    return data
}
```

Here are the outputs:

print(data) //1:
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, {tons of doubles}, 0.0]

print(data) //2:
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

What am I missing?

Comment: The //1 should be printed after //2, no? You are missing the asynchrone of `perform(query:inZoneWith:completion:)`. You need to use yourself a closure.

Comment: Thank you @Larme , I definitely missed this, it's also my first time working with asynchrone calls. I'll read something about it and update this post as soon as I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the new synch tools;

```
 func fetchUserRecord() async throws -> [Double]
 {
     var data: [Double] = [0, 1, 2]    // you don't really want the              
     let aWeekAgo = Date().addingTimeInterval(-604800)

    let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Date > %@", aWeekAgo as NSDate)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ProgressionValue", predicate: predicate)
    let (values, cursor) = try await privateDB.records(matching: query, resultsLimit: 100)

    for r in values
    {
        if let rec = try? r.1.get()
        {                
            data.append(rec["value"] as Double)
        }
    }
    
    return x
        
  }
```

Call it like this;

```
Task 
{
   do {
         data = try await fetchUserRecord()           
      }
      catch
      {
         print(error)
      }
 }
```